# How do you get a git log output from a shelljs.exec command?

Tags: git, logging, gruntjs

I need to put a git log into a file.
The command line works fine

[Git log command line result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM13U.png)

But if I call this command with a grunt task using shelljs.exec, I dont get any output

[Git log with grunt task using shelljs.exec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzZrY.png)

Here the grunt code :

```
/*global module:false,require,console*/
'use strict';

var shell = require('shelljs');


module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        // Task configuration.
    });

    grunt.task.registerTask('git-log', 'git log output', function () {
        console.log('RESULT : ', shell.exec('git log HEAD...HEAD^ --oneline',{silent : true}).output);
    });

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['git-log']);

};
```

I checked all the shelljs docs and tried different ways (including async) with no success...

Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: Could you try this and post the result ? `grunt.log.writeln( JSON.stringify( shell.exec('git log HEAD...HEAD^ --oneline', {silent : true}), null, 2 ) );`

Comment: Running "git-log" task
{"code": 0,
  "output": ""
}

Done, without errors.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It seems there is not output when the command succeeds (code = 0). I'm going to check something then I'll get back to you.

Comment: Do you have to use shelljs absolutely ? Because this module https://github.com/juliangruber/git-log may be a solution.

Comment: Yes, I need to append the log result into a file (Im using file-creator task) with another input

Comment: You could retrieve the log result with another module than shelljs.

Comment: JFYI : the output is ok with a "node -v" command... Looks like its related to   git log

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.stdout` instead of `.output`.

In your code:

```
shell.exec(
  'git log HEAD...HEAD^ --oneline',
  {silent : true}
).output;
```

Change to:

```
shell.exec(
  'git log HEAD...HEAD^ --oneline',
  {silent : true}
).stdout;
```